# fast gui on raspberry

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi

I started a project where you can "log in" on a terminal (basically a Raspberry Pi with a touchscreen attached) with a wireless token (for time tracking).

What will be the **best and fastest solution** to display the status (basically a background picture and 2-3 texts changing depending on the status of the token) on the screen (fullscreen)? I tried it web-based with chromium, which is -very- slow...

It has to be easy to do **http request** and en-/decoding **JSON** - and please no C/C++.
Maybe python + wxwidgets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want easy/fast, and all you care about is http, JSON, and displaying an image, then I'd go with Tkinter and the standard library.

You have `import json` for JSON, and `httplib` or `urrlib2` for http requests. And for a fullscreen Tkinter widget, check out [effbot](http://www.effbot.org/zone/tkinter-toplevel-fullscreen.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You could use Python for this easily with just the standard library (python 2.7.3).

For the GUI you can use `Tkinter` or `Pygame (not standard library)` which both support images and text placement (and full screen). It is notable that `Tkinter` is not thread safe, so that may be a problem if your planning on threading this program.

For the http request you can use `httplib`.

For the Json related things you can use the `json` library.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly give QT a try. It has very good GUI tools and supports the C++ and nativeness it requires. We use  QT to build interface and deploy it small terminals such as raspberry Pi. It will also allow you to boot straight in to the application as it starts. 
Here is a link : http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-RaspberryPi